# iOS EZAudio get the record time and file duration

Tags: ios, core-audio, avaudiorecorder

I am using the EZAudio framework which you can find [here](https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio). I am having a hard time figuring out how to get the record time and total time of my audio file. As I am recording, I would like one label to show the position of the seeker, and another label to show total time of the recording. Example: 2:23 | 3:32. The position label would be updated every second, and the total time label would only start updating if the user recorded beyond the total time to make the file longer.

What I've tried: I am a total noob when it comes to core audio. I am using the OpenGL audio plot from the EZAudio library which gets updated as I record, so there's gotta be a way to do some conversion to calculate the time.

For the total time I thought about preparing an AVAudioPlayer with the file, grab the duration that way, but that only works if the user isn't recording. If they are recording, then I need a way to update both times on the fly.

In another app I use AVAudioRecorder (which doesn't work for my purposes), and I can create an `NSTimer` and have it fire the `timerUpdate` function:

```
_timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01f
                                              target:self
                                            selector:@selector(timerUpdate)
                                            userInfo:nil
                                             repeats:YES];

- (void) timerUpdate
{
if (_recording)
{
    int m = _recorder.currentTime / 60;
    int s = ((int) _recorder.currentTime) % 60;   

    _duration.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2d:%.2d", m, s];


}
if (_playing)
{
    _progress.progress = _player.currentTime/_player.duration;
}

}
```

The EZRecorder doesn't have a `currentTime` method, so this doesn't work. I'm not asking for you to write the code for me, just point me in the right direction.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your use case. Is the user overdubbing a track? So the 3:32 in your example is the length of the original file and the 2:23 is the location/current time in the current recording/overdubbed file?

Comment: Not overdubbing, but overwriting. They slide the seeker to the point they want to start recording, say to fix a mistake. Then when they record, everything from 2:23 until they stop is overwritten.

Comment: Got it. In your callback you have access to the number of frames - inNumberFrames - so you can use that to calculate your current record time (AudioUnitRender()). Then, do some arithmetic to calculate an offset from where the user started recording in the original file.

Comment: I see the callback in the EZMicrophone.m file. I guess I just don't know how to access that data from my view controller. I have an EZMicrophone initialized, but there aren't any public methods to call to get inNumberFrames. Like I said, noob.

Comment: EZMicrophone uses the Delegate pattern (if you don't know what a delegate is see this [intro](http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns)) and makes the audio data available to you via the `EZMicrophoneDelegate`. So, when initializing your viewController make it a delegate of EZMicrophone and then you can use the delegate methods `microphone:hasAudioReceived:withBufferSize:withNumberOfChannels:` or `microphone:hasBufferList:withBufferSize:withNumberOfChannels:` to get the audio data and count the frames.

Comment: No luck. I am out of my league here. I had those delegate methods in my view controller. The inNumberFrames is just 1024. I'm not sure what to do with that. What I really need is the number of the current frame being recorded and a way to convert that to time. I see an AudioTimeStamp in the EZMicrophone.m which has a member called mSampleTime defined as "the absolute sample frame time." But I don't know how to get a reference to it.

Comment: There's a little work involved in that you need to unpack the AudioBufferList and keep a running tally of frames/samples. Not super hard but if you've not been programming long then could be a challenge. In essence you'd want to create a static variable that you update/increment with the number of samples/frames being passed each time the callback gets called. Are you using an EZOutput module? That has a callback with an `inTimeStamp` attribute that might contain the data you want. Sorry, I've never used EZAudio. Try looking for an EZAudio forum or post an issue to GitHub. Good Luck!

Comment: EZAudio gives currentTime property which will give recorded time of the audio. Recorder example